# Inverse Laplace with $\ln$

Tags: integration, laplace-transform, contour-integration

How can I compute the inverse Laplace of

1) $\ln\left(\dfrac{s+1}{s-1}\right)$

2) $\ln\left(\dfrac{s-1}{s}\right)$.
Can someone please hep me to do these two problems

Comment: Using contour integration, specifically the Bromwich contour, it can be shown that $$\mathcal{L}^{-1} \Big\{ \ln \left(\frac{s+1}{s-1}\right) \Big\}(t) = \int_{-1}^{1} e^{ts} \ ds = \frac{2 \sinh t}{t}$$

and

$$ \mathcal{L}^{-1} \Big\{\ln  \left(\frac{s-1}{s}\right) \Big\}(t) = -\int_{0}^{1} e^{ts} \ ds = \frac{1-e^{t}}{t}$$

Comment: See, for example, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/545490/inversion-of-laplace-transform-fs-log-fracs1s-bromwich-integral/545562#545562

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\wt}[1]{\widetilde{#1}}$
$\ds{\large\tt\mbox{With}\quad \gamma > 1:}$
\begin{align}&\color{#66f}{\large%
\int_{\gamma - \infty\ic}^{\gamma + \infty\ic}
\ln\pars{s + 1 \over s - 1}\,\expo{st}\,{\dd s \over 2\pi\ic}}
=\int_{\gamma - \infty\ic}^{\gamma + \infty\ic}
\int_{-1}^{1}{\dd x \over x + s}\,\expo{st}\,{\dd s \over 2\pi\ic}
\\[3mm]&=\int_{-1}^{1}\int_{\gamma - \infty\ic}^{\gamma + \infty\ic}
{\expo{st} \over s + x}\,{\dd s \over 2\pi\ic}\,\dd x
=\int_{-1}^{1}\expo{-xt}\,\dd x
={\expo{-t} - \expo{t}  \over -t} = \color{#66f}{\large{2\sinh\pars{t} \over t}}
\end{align}

> The other one can be evaluated in a similar way.

Comment: Nice answer. +1 I deleted my answer because it was too hard to explain without a picture of the contour.

Comment: @RandomVariable It's somehow cumbersome to work directly with the $\large\ln$. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Given
\begin{align}
\mathcal{L}\{f(t); s\} = \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-st} f(t) \ dt
\end{align}
then the inverse Laplace transforms are given by the following
\begin{align}
\mathcal{L}\{ \frac{2 \sinh(at)}{t}; s\} = \ln\left(\frac{s+a}{s-a}\right)
\end{align}
and
\begin{align}
\mathcal{L}\{ \frac{1 - e^{at}}{t}; s\} = \ln\left(\frac{s-a}{s}\right).
\end{align}

The process to find the values given above is to use the relation
\begin{align}
\mathcal{L}\{ \frac{f(t)}{t}; s\} = \int_{s}^{\infty} g(u) \ du
\end{align}
where 
\begin{align}
g(s) = \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{- st} f(t) \ dt.
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

Podes usar algunas propiedades de las transformadas.

[You can use some properties of the transforms]

Ej; [Example]

$$((-1)^n) (t^n) f(t)=F^n(s)$$

Donde f(t) es la antitransformada de $F^n(s)$.

[Where $f(t)$ is in the inverse transform of $F^{n}(s)$.